# How to disable [VM]XXX debugger in Chrome while debugging javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I want to debug a piece of javascript function line-by-line in Chrome browser, but everytime the chrome's '**Source**' is opening in some **[VM]XXX** mode and I cannot see which exact line I'm debugging. It's just showing whole block of function, not letting me show line-by-line debug.

See the ss below:
[image]

If you notice, the line-by-line debugging is not enabled. How can I see/debug line-by-line so that I can understand in which line exactly I'm right now, and which line causing error and why?? Is there any disable/enable for this **[VM]XXX** mode in chrome?

Comment: `VM` means it's a dynamically created script e.g. by using `eval`, `new Function`, or appending a DOM `script` element with the code inside not from `src`. This is what your code or compiler/bundler does so you'll need to change it. Still, usually it's possible to debug such scripts line by line so in your case maybe there's a problem with Source Maps.

Comment: You're write,, what I already did was,, `disabled` the Source Maps. And now I can debug line-by-line my javascript in chrome. To uncheck the source maps, I went to,  **F12 > Settings > Preferences > Sources > Enable JavaScript source maps** .

Answer (score 3):

### Open an **incognito** window and make sure to disable all Chrome Extensions from running in *incognito mode*.

VMxxx tabs will be opened when Chrome Extensions are running. Instead of manually adding every files to the ignore list, you can disable the Chrome Extensions altogether.

[Blackbox Chrome VMXXX Scripts] -
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=526239